# Merge - Only update if values have changed

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

I am running a merge in SQL Server. In my update, I want to only update the row if the values have changed. There is a version row that increments on each update. Below is an example:

```
MERGE Employee as tgt USING 
(SELECT Employee_History.Emp_ID
, Employee_History.First_Name
, Employee_History.Last_Name
FROM Employee_History)
as src (Emp_ID,First_Name,Last_Name)
ON tgt.Emp_ID = src.Emp_ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET
    Emp_ID = src.Emp_ID,
    ,[VERSION] = tgt.VERSION + 1 
    ,First_Name = src.First_Name
    ,Last_Name = src.Last_Name
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY target THEN 
    INSERT (Emp_ID,0,First_Name,Last_Name)
VALUES 
    (src.Emp_ID,[VERSION],src.First_Name,src.Last_Name);
```

Now, if I only wanted to update the row, and thus increment version, ONLY if the name has changed.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`WHEN MATCHED` can have `AND` . Also, no need to update `EMP_ID` .

```
...
 WHEN MATCHED AND (trg.First_Name <> src.First_Name 
   OR trg.Last_Name <> src.Last_Name) THEN UPDATE
   SET 
   [VERSION] = tgt.VERSION + 1 
    ,First_Name = src.First_Name
    ,Last_Name = src.Last_Name
 ...
```

If Last_Name or First_Name are nullable, you need to take care of `NULL` values while comparing trg.Last_Name <> src.Last_Name , for instance `ISNULL(trg.Last_Name,'') <> ISNULL(src.Last_Name,'')`

Comment: Should this be an 'or'? If just the first name changed, I still want to update

Comment: I think this will work perfectly. I didn't realize I could have an 'AND' on the MATCHED part. Thank you.

Comment: i've tried doing this, but when i OUTPUT $action, deleted.*, inserted.*, i am seeing everything got updated, it might be negligible to some, but when there are triggers or big data within the columns, it will be a problem. I'm currently stuck and i don't wish to write a mega case within the merge

Comment: @LeeGary, Are you saying that `WHEN MATCHED AND (...)` will still populate `inserted.*` even though no update occurred due non-matching condition?

Comment: What about in the case that you have too many columns to write AND cases for? If you have 20 columns and only want to be updating 1 changed row, is there a way to only update that one? It would be ridiculous to write that many AND/OR cases for WHEN MATCHED. Or is updating all the rows (even when not changed) not a big deal in terms of cost?

Comment: @user7733611 : updating all rows in such case shouldn't have a big performance penalty assuming no LOB fields are involved, but in any case if field value changes, the engine must update index if any (it might be smart enough to detect value is the same, but still it must at least find it).  Filling condition for `WHEN MATCHED` doesn't seem to be a problem , verbose - yes, but it just a repetition of `SET` part to a greater extent.

Comment: oracle DB does not take this construction, it is not working, better and add where clause in update statement

Comment: I suggest also use ISNULL method

Answer (score 3):

The answer provided by a1ex07 is the right answer, but i just wanted to expand on the difficulty in comparing a large number of columns, watching for nulls, etc.

I found that I could generate a checksum in some CTE's with hashbytes, target those CTEs in the merge, and then use the "update and...." condition specified above to compare the hashes:

```
with SourcePermissions as (
    SELECT 1 as Code, 1013 as ObjectTypeCode, 'Create Market' as ActionName, null as ModuleCode, 1 as AssignableTargetFlags
    union all SELECT 2, 1013, 'View Market', null, 1
    union all SELECT 3, 1013, 'Edit Market', null, 1
    --...shortened....
)
,SourcePermissions2 as (
    select sp.*, HASHBYTES('sha2_256', xmlcol)  as [Checksum] 
    from SourcePermissions sp
    cross apply (select sp.* for xml raw) x(xmlcol)
)
,TargetPermissions as (
    select p.*, HASHBYTES('sha2_256', xmlcol)  as [Checksum] 
    from Permission p
    cross apply (select p.* for xml raw) x(xmlcol)
) --select * from SourcePermissions2 sp join TargetPermissions tp on sp.code=tp.code where sp.Checksum = tp.Checksum

    MERGE TargetPermissions AS target  
    USING (select * from SourcePermissions2) AS source ([Code] , [ObjectTypeCode] , [ActionName] , [ModuleCode] , [AssignableTargetFlags], [Checksum])  
        ON (target.Code = source.Code)  
    WHEN MATCHED and source.[Checksum] != target.[Checksum] then
        UPDATE SET [ObjectTypeCode] = source.[ObjectTypeCode], [ActionName]=source.[ActionName], [ModuleCode]=source.[ModuleCode], [AssignableTargetFlags] = source.[AssignableTargetFlags]
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN  
        INSERT ([Code] , [ObjectTypeCode] , [ActionName] , [ModuleCode] , [AssignableTargetFlags])  
        VALUES (source.[Code] , source.[ObjectTypeCode] , source.[ActionName] , source.[ModuleCode] , source.[AssignableTargetFlags])
    OUTPUT deleted.*, $action, inserted.[Code] 
        --only minor issue is that you can no longer do a inserted.* here since it gives error 404 (sql, not web), complaining about returning checksum which is included in the target cte but not the underlying table
        ,inserted.[ObjectTypeCode] , inserted.[ActionName] , inserted.[ModuleCode] , inserted.[AssignableTargetFlags]
    ;
```

Couple of notes: I could have simplified greatly with checksum or binary_checksum, but I always get collisions with those.

As to the 'why', this is part of an automated deployment to keep a lookup table up to date. The problem with the merge though is there is an indexed view that is complex and heavily used, so updates to the related tables are quite expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than avoiding an update altogether, you could change your `[VERSION] + 1` code to add zero when names match:

```
[VERSION] = tgt.VERSION + (CASE
    WHEN tgt.First_Name <> src.First_Name OR tgt.Last_Name <> src.Last_Name
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: This could work as well, but @a1ex07 answer is a little more to my needs as there is no need to update the values if nothing changed.

Comment: I am using SQL Versioned Tables (temporal) and that puts a replica row in if updated, so I would use @a1ex07's answer rather than this one

Answer (score 1):

One refinement to the accepted answer is that you can use a "exists (old except new)" clause for the `WHEN MATCHED AND` section, as found in this clever blog post: https://chadbaldwin.net/2020/12/30/only-update-rows-that-changed.html

```
 WHEN MATCHED 
 AND exists(
               select src.First_Name, src.Last_Name
               except
               select trg.First_Name, trg.Last_Name
            )
THEN UPDATE ...
```

This can greatly simplify what would have been huge swaths of `ISNULL`s.

Answer (score -1):

@a1ex07 thanks for the answer.. a slight correction.. I am not following SQL version so this could be a change in SQL specification

WHEN MATCHED **AND CONDITION** THEN UPDATE

The above is not a valid syntax

Following is valid

WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET ... **WHERE CONDITION** WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT...

so would change it to

```
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
   SET 
   [VERSION] = tgt.VERSION + 1 
   ,First_Name = src.First_Name
   ,Last_Name = src.Last_Name
```

**WHERE
     trg.First_Name <> src.First_Name 
      OR trg.Last_Name <> src.Last_Name**

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606

Comment: please read and improve your activity https://stackoverflow.com/tour   thank you

Comment: Please pay attention to the tags. Question is for MS SQL Server and you are referring Oracle syntax.