# Insert new records and update changed records in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in `SQL Server` which I want insert new records or update the record if the value has changed.  The `merge` command appears to be close, but if the record already exists, it will update it no matter what.  The functionality I am looking to find is to "skip" if each column of the source is the same as the target.

Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE #Clients (
    ClientID int PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName varchar(20),
    InsertedDate datetime default getdate(),
    ModifiedDate datetime default getdate()
    );

INSERT INTO #Clients (ClientID, FirstName)
VALUES (1, 'Fred'), (2, 'Barney'), (3, 'Betty');

CREATE TABLE #Source (
    ClientID int PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName varchar(20),
    InsertedDate datetime default getdate(),
    ModifiedDate datetime default getdate()
    );

INSERT INTO #Source (ClientID, FirstName)
VALUES (1,'Fred'), (2, 'Fred Jr.'), (4, 'Wilma');

USE tempdb;
GO
BEGIN TRAN;
MERGE #Clients AS C
USING #Source AS S ON (C.ClientID = S.ClientID) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN INSERT(ClientID, FirstName) VALUES(S.ClientID, S.FirstName)
WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN UPDATE SET C.FirstName = S.FirstName, ModifiedDate = GETDATE()
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
    THEN DELETE 
OUTPUT $action, inserted.*, deleted.*;
GO
```

Is there a way to write this to only update a record if it's changed?

Comment: To do this you would have to write your own "upsert" and check the value for each column. Keep in mind you may have to use a case sensitive collation in your checking if you want to capture changes in case for string values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge - Only update if values have changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16107273/merge-only-update-if-values-have-changed)